# How to check if the variable is a String

Tags: c#, .net, string, for-loop

I have a simple problem,

**dtERP value = 2885,78,89,78A;**

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtERP.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dtERP.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        object field = dtERP.Rows[j]["QTY"];
        if (field != int)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I validate my field if the value is string?

Comment: Please only add relevant tags to your question. Also, your current code doesn't make sense (given the initial value of dtERP, it can't be a `DataTable`). What does "how can I validate my field if the value have a string character" mean?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Comment: uhm. something like ``if (Convert.ToInt32(field) != true) {error}``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) operator. Something like this:

```
if(field is string)
```

Comment: Do note that if the original value is `"7"`, it is still a string - a database column cannot store both strings and numbers. But this particular value may be *converted* to an int

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [`.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) on the variable/instance.